# nslookup showing a lot of information

Tags: nslookup

I am taking a CS course and we're looking into the nslookup command. When my instructor does it he gets only the non authoritative results. When I type it, I get a ton of info with the info I'm looking for based on the -type== option than I input hidden amongst it. Here's my output. is this normal?

I ran nslookup -type==NS starwars.com

main parsing starwars.com

addlookup()

make_empty_lookup()

make_empty_lookup() = 0x7f9118d9e000->references = 1

looking up starwars.com

lock_lookup dighost.c:4184

success

start_lookup()

setup_lookup(0x7f9118d9e000)

resetting lookup counter.

cloning server list

clone_server_list()

make_server(75.75.75.75)

make_server(75.75.76.76)

idn_textname: starwars.com

using root origin

recursive query

add_question()

starting to render the message

done rendering

create query 0x7f9117a2d000 linked to lookup 0x7f9118d9e000

dighost.c:2083:lookup_attach(0x7f9118d9e000) = 2

dighost.c:2587:new_query(0x7f9117a2d000) = 1

create query 0x7f9117a2d1c0 linked to lookup 0x7f9118d9e000

dighost.c:2083:lookup_attach(0x7f9118d9e000) = 3

dighost.c:2587:new_query(0x7f9117a2d1c0) = 1

do_lookup()

start_udp(0x7f9117a2d000)

dighost.c:2936:query_attach(0x7f9117a2d000) = 2

working on lookup 0x7f9118d9e000, query 0x7f9117a2d000

dighost.c:2981:query_attach(0x7f9117a2d000) = 3

unlock_lookup dighost.c:4186

dighost.c:2898:query_attach(0x7f9117a2d000) = 4

recving with lookup=0x7f9118d9e000, query=0x7f9117a2d000, handle=(nil)

recvcount=1

have local timeout of 5000

dighost.c:2847:query_attach(0x7f9117a2d000) = 5

sending a request

sendcount=1

dighost.c:1676:query_detach(0x7f9117a2d000) = 4

dighost.c:2918:query_detach(0x7f9117a2d000) = 3

send_done(0x7f9117a8d000, success, 0x7f9117a2d000)

sendcount=0

lock_lookup dighost.c:2615

success

dighost.c:2629:lookup_attach(0x7f9118d9e000) = 4

dighost.c:2648:query_detach(0x7f9117a2d000) = 2

dighost.c:2649:lookup_detach(0x7f9118d9e000) = 3

check_if_done()

list empty

unlock_lookup dighost.c:2652

recv_done(0x7f9117a8d000, success, 0x7f91187fa010, 0x7f9117a2d000)

lock_lookup dighost.c:3577

success

recvcount=0

dighost.c:3589:lookup_attach(0x7f9118d9e000) = 4

before parse starts

after parse

printmessage()

Server:         75.75.75.75

Address:        75.75.75.75#53

Non-authoritative answer:

printsection()

starwars.com    nameserver = a28-65.akam.net.

starwars.com    nameserver = a9-66.akam.net.

starwars.com    nameserver = a13-67.akam.net.

starwars.com    nameserver = a12-66.akam.net.

starwars.com    nameserver = a18-64.akam.net.

starwars.com    nameserver = a1-127.akam.net.

Authoritative answers can be found from:

printsection()

printsection()

a9-66.akam.net  internet address = 184.85.248.66

a9-66.akam.net  has AAAA address 2a02:26f0:117::42

a13-67.akam.net internet address = 2.22.230.67

a13-67.akam.net has AAAA address 2600:1480:800::43

a12-66.akam.net internet address = 184.26.160.66

a18-64.akam.net internet address = 95.101.36.64

a1-127.akam.net internet address = 193.108.91.127

a1-127.akam.net has AAAA address 2600:1401:2::7f

a28-65.akam.net internet address = 95.100.173.65

still pending.

dighost.c:4079:query_detach(0x7f9117a2d000) = 1

dighost.c:4081:_cancel_lookup()

dighost.c:2669:query_detach(0x7f9117a2d000) = 0

dighost.c:2669:destroy_query(0x7f9117a2d000) = 0

dighost.c:1634:lookup_detach(0x7f9118d9e000) = 3

dighost.c:2669:query_detach(0x7f9117a2d1c0) = 0

dighost.c:2669:destroy_query(0x7f9117a2d1c0) = 0

dighost.c:1634:lookup_detach(0x7f9118d9e000) = 2

check_if_done()

list empty

dighost.c:4087:lookup_detach(0x7f9118d9e000) = 1

clear_current_lookup()

dighost.c:1759:lookup_detach(0x7f9118d9e000) = 0

destroy_lookup

freeing server 0x7f9117a12000 belonging to 0x7f9118d9e000

freeing server 0x7f9117a12a00 belonging to 0x7f9118d9e000

start_lookup()

check_if_done()

list empty

shutting down

dighost_shutdown()

unlock_lookup dighost.c:4091

done, and starting to shut down

cancel_all()

lock_lookup dighost.c:4200

success

unlock_lookup dighost.c:4231

destroy_libs()

freeing task

lock_lookup dighost.c:4251

success

flush_server_list()

destroy DST lib

unlock_lookup dighost.c:4279

Removing log context

Destroy memory

Just seeing if this is the normal output, because on my instructors screen, he only gets the Authoritative and Non Authoritative sections.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it relates to this: https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=7522

Try adding -nod2 when you run the command.